# How can I update retrieval of Rails.application.credentials after rails credentials:edit dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't have direct access to production servers for deployment. I can only open up pods and run the Ruby on Rails console in production. To update any configurations, I need to help from the [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) team to update environment variables and restart the pods so that configurations take effect. However, this process is tedious, and I need the ability to dynamically update the credentials as it’s hard to coordinate with multiple teams while rotating credentials.

I need to get Ruby on Rails credentials updated dynamically without the need to restart application servers or the rails console. How can I achieve this in Ruby on Rails application credentials?

Comment: Does running `reload!` in the rails console work?

Comment: Sorry just saw that you said you don’t want to restart the rails console. Another idea is if you can manually manipulate `Rails.application.credentials` from inside the console. I think that may achieve the same thing without need for restart

Comment: I need dynamic update of credentials. There is a 3rd party service that is used in product whose credentials need rotation. So, when that application credentials are changed, I need to update them in the codebase. After adding in code, I need to get the pods restarted from devops team.
I want to remove my dependancy from devops team and get the latest credentials in the code dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Rails [custom credentials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials).

From [Rails 6 onwards](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33521), you can create separate encrypted credential files for each environment. For example, for `production` environment, run:

```
rails credentials:edit --environment production
```

It'll do the following:

- Creates a `config/credentials/production.key` if missing. It would be best if you did not commit it to your version control(it's added to `.gitignore` by default anyway). Then you can set this key as `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` to your hosting environment i.e. in Heroku `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=the_above_production.key`.
- Creates a `config/credentials/production.yml.enc` if missing. It's an encrypted version of your environment variables. You can add it to your version control safely.
- Decrypts the contents of `config/credentials/production.yml.enc` and opens it in your default editor. For the first run, it'll be empty as there's nothing encrypted.

Add the following in the newly opened window and save:

```yaml
secret_key_base: secret
mystery: revealed
```

You can check the contents loaded in `rails c --environment=production`

```rb
Rails.application.credentials.mystery
# revealed
```

Every time you want to update the credentials, run the `rails credentials:edit --environment production` command, make necessary changes, and push the updated `config/credentials/production.yml.enc` file to your version control. Hopefully, it'll save you some time!